# Validação de datas em javascript usando datas no padrão aaa-mm-dd em PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Fala galera...

Seguinte, estou precisando implementar opção de "Suspender Contrato" de um aluno. Essa suspensão só poderá ser aplicada no intervalo da vigência do contrato desse aluno. Supondo que o aluno tem seu contrato com vigência de 01/01/2020 até 31/12/2022 e a suspensão desse contrato SÓ deve ser aplicada entre essas duas datas.

Tenho o código abaixo, mas não sei onde ou o quê está errado.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function checarDatas()
    {
        var dataCI = (document.forms[0]["contratoIncio"].value).split("/");
        var dataCF = (document.forms[0]["contratoFim"].value).split("/");

        var dataSI = (document.forms[0]["suspensaoInicio"].value).split("/");
        var dataSF = (document.forms[0]["suspensaoFim"].value).split("/");

        var dataInformadaSI = new Date(dataSI[2], dataSI[1]-1, dataSI[0]);
        var dataInformadaSF = new Date(dataSF[2], dataSF[1]-1, dataSF[0]);      

        var dataInformadaCI = new Date(dataCI[2], dataCI[1]-1, dataCI[0]);
        var dataInformadaCF = new Date(dataCF[2], dataCF[1]-1, dataCF[0]);      


        if ( dataInformadaSI >= dataInformadaCI && dataInformadaSF <= dataInformadaCF )
        {
            alert("Datas OK!");
        }
        else 
        {
            alert("A data de suspensao escolhida, esta fora da vigencia do contrato.");
            document.getElementById('suspensaoInicio').value="";
            document.getElementById('suspensaoFim').value="";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Minha página está em PHP. Possuo uma query que traz do BD as datas do contrato no formato "aaaa-mm-dd".

Espero ter sido claro.

Obrigado quem puder ajudar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer rodar como precisava!

Compare os dois códigos e observe o que estava de errado no 1º. O código abaixo está rodando 100% como preciso.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function checarDatas()
    {
        var dataCI = document.getElementById('contratoInicio').value;
        var dataCF = document.getElementById('contratoFim').value;

        var dataSI = document.getElementById('suspensaoInicio').value;
        var dataSF = document.getElementById('suspensaoFim').value;

        if ( dataSI >= dataCI && dataSF <= dataCF )
        {
//          alert("Datas OK!");
        }
        else 
        {
            alert("O periodo de suspensao esta fora da vigência do contrato.");
            document.getElementById('suspensaoInicio').value="";
            document.getElementById('suspensaoFim').value="";
        }
    }
</script>
```